# Need to support network based authentication

Tags: java, authentication, active-directory, ldap

Are there any libraries that can authenticate via active directory?

This is a new application, so I want to make the correct design patterns in the beginning.  I want my authentication service to be able to support my session/cookie based authentication and active directory/ldap.

Are there any examples online that I can look over that provide the same sort of functionality? Or maybe a library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if there are any java examples out there, but this site has a ton of C# examples.  All of the logic would be the same.  Hope this helps somewhat.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx